# Pagination query for a Oracle database returns duplicate entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out the root cause of an issue wherein pagination (in Oracle) using rownum returns duplicate results. The query works fine with my oracle database. However, it doesn't work with a different database wherein this query returns duplicate results.

The above queries return expected results when they are run against my database. However, the values fetched with the first query are fetched again with the second query as well when run against a different oracle database.

For example:

Query 1 returns a column of values: x y z

Query 2 returns a column of values: y x

However, query 3 returns a column of values: a b z y x

The queries look something like this:

```
select id, data 
from t where rownum <= 3; //Returns the first 3 results
```

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, rownum rnum
  from (
    select id, data
    from t
  ) a
  where rownum <= 6
)
where rnum > 3; //returns the next 3 results
```

```
select id, data from t;
```

Expected Result:

Query 1 should return a column of values: a b z

Query 2 should return a column of values: y x

Comment: What do you mean by 'when run against a different oracle database'? Do the two databases have the same data?

Comment: That first query is not syntactically valid.  You can't have a WHERE following an ORDER BY.  Are you missing a nested subquery there?

Comment: What is ordering by rowid expected to achieve? It's the physical file/block/offset storage location, obviously it is not reliable as a business ordering key.

Comment: @Josh Eller, the two databases have "similar" data. They store the data for an application. To be specific, they store data for installations of an application.

Comment: @Williamson the "order by" part isn't what the problem is about. I copy pasted a query from a different place and modified it to make it look similar to my query. I updated the query so that there's no more confusion regarding the "order by" part of the query.

Comment: The first query, as currently modified, asks for an arbitrary three rows.  It is perfectly valid for it to return any three rows from the table.  If you want a specific three rows, you'd need to have an ORDER BY.  At which point you'd presumably want to use the second query asking for rows 1-3 rather than 4-6